# Hibernate 5.1.2 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions

Tags: hibernate, classpath

I recently upgraded from Hibernate 4.3.10 to 5.2.12 and when I try to deploy the application on wildfly 9 using java 8, I get below error.

Here is my relevant pom.xml snippet.

```
       <properties>
            <org.hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</org.hibernate.version>
        </properties>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And here is the stacktrace.

> 14:45:49,300 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."your.war#yourdb":
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."your.war#yourdb":
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions
>         at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
>         at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
>         at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:665)
>         at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>         at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.applyInjections(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:278)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:269)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:295)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2444)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2440)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
>         at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
>         at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
>         ... 7 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions from [Module
>   "deployment.your.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>         at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
>         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
>         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
>         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
>         at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)

Any idea what can be wrong in my environment ?

Comment: Could you check your build path once? Probably there is still reference to old jar versions.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this happens when you have different hibernate versions on your classpath.

Comment: Thanks but mine is a simple project with just on pom.xml and I run 'mvn clean install' so it should have the latest hibernate jars in the .war file.I am not able to understand from where its trying to reference the old version ?

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly has its own Hibernate module. You can try to exclude it using `exclusions`.

An example of using exclusions from here
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/topical/html_single/wildfly/Wildfly.html

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.javassist" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: I think you are right. What I discovered now that every wildfly version comes with a default version of hibernate. In my case, for wildfly9 it was hibernate 4.3.1 and thats what is being referred. I found a documentation about it here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/topical/html_single/wildfly/Wildfly.html which is useful and I and going to try this now. Meanwhile I would like to know how to use 'exclusion' ?